# clip-path takes up space for the whole image?

Tags: html, css, clip, image-clipping

I'm trying to show only a part of the image, but it takes up the height inside my box for the whole image when I only want to take up the height for the part I'm showing.

In my example code below, note the light blue background showing behind the image.
How can I prevent this?

```css
span {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
img {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 64%, 0 64%);
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</span>
```

Comment: @showdev I accidentally pasted the wrong code version, I've added it now.

Comment: I see. Do you mean that the image with `clip-path` still takes up the full height of the unclipped image?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to stop it taking the full height and only take height of the part that's clipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `clip-path` to the span instead But be aware that `clip-path` **doesn't remove** the non-visible part.

```css
span {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 64%, 0 64%);
}
p {
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</span>
<p>some text here</p>
```

You can avoid the `clip-path` by using fixed height on the span and setting `overflow:hidden` and in this case you will remove the non-needed part:

```css
span {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
p {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</span>
<p>some text here</p>
```

Another idea is to also use the image as background:

```css
span {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height:100px;
  width:350px;
}
p {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<span style="background-image:url(//via.placeholder.com/350x150)">
</span>
<p>some text here</p>
```

Comment: @showdev yes and in this case he need to understand how clip-path work ... it clip and it doens't cut

Comment: This still shows the space at the bottom of the box.

Comment: @burido yes ;) this the behavior of clip-path ... iadded more explanation and an alternative

Comment: The alternative still doesn't fix this.

Comment: @burido how it doesn't fix ? :)

Comment: `<p class="image"><span style=" float: left; background-color: lightblue; height:100px; overflow:hidden;"> <img style="margin-top:-20px;" src="figure?figure={{ Auth::user()->look }}&gesture=sml&size=m"></p> </span>`

Comment: UPDATE: After changing the height to 50px, it fixed it. Thank you!